# how can I work my online java web application to work in offline?

Tags: persistence

I want to add the feature of database synchronization to my project. It should be like this:

1. When the internet connection is available the application should transact with the online database server.
2. When the internet connection is not available it should keep track of the transactions and should update the local DB to online DB server when connection is available it should synchronize.

How can I do this?

Before that we are using **Multi Tenant concept** in our web application. Single online DB can access all clients using multiple schema.

I want to know how can my web application work in offline mode. If I use HTML5 application cache concept means the HTML and CSS file will load from cookies. How can I get the database value from database when application goes offline.

What is a good way to make my application work online and offline with database?

Answer (score 0):

Most modern browsers have databases or persistence facilities similar to a database for pretty much exactly this use case.

You may end up having to dive pretty deep into *javascript* to get it to work though.  (Especially when the online DB comes back online and you have to go back through all the offline data and send it up (post) to the server end)

Comment: how can I get old database value when application goes offline.then only my application work.